# flash at32f403 with st-link using openocd

Tags: linux, st-link, openocd

I'm trying to flash my hoverboard which has the at32f403 chip and the procedure to do that according to the github is describe in the link below:

https://github.com/cloidnerux/hoverboard-firmware-hack

But I got a error below after tried to execute the command
openocd -f interface/stlink-v2.cfg -f target/stm32f1x.cfg -c init -c "reset halt" -c "stm32f1x unlock 0"

Additional info:
I'm usign ubuntu and latest version of openocd  (0.11.0). I also added the code below in the src/flash/nor/stm32f1x.c in order to recognize the chip (part of the cloidnerux procedure)

case 0x242: /* AT32F403 */
page_size = 2048;
stm32x_info->ppage_size = 2;
max_flash_size_in_kb = 512;
break;

command:

$ openocd -f interface/stlink-v2.cfg -f target/stm32f0x.cfg

error:

```
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.9.0 (2015-07-26-16:02)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : auto-selecting first available session transport "hla_swd". To 
override use 'transport select <transport>'.
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The 
results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
Info : clock speed 1000 kHz
```

Anyone can help me I'm stuck on this like 2 months!!

Really appreciate it!

Regards,
Bruno O.

Comment: I got another error :
libusb_open() failed with libusb_error_access
and the lsusb shows the st link device.
Any insight?

Comment: I figure it out, later I'll post on github